# JLable not change after change the TextFiled and also the combox

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcombobox

Hi I'm doing a program that firstly opens setting menu like in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iAUW.png)

first I select the choices of the game I want from the jcombox and jdialog that open window to set the names .

this is the code of it :

```
public class SettingMenu extends JFrame   {

boolean is3players = false, is4players = false;

BufferedImage settingImage;

String[] playersChoises = { "2", "3", "4" };
String[] sizeChoises = { "30", "50", "100" };

JComboBox comboBoxPlayers;
JComboBox comboBoxSizes;

static JButton startGame, writeNames;

public SettingMenu() {


    JLabel howManyPlayersText = new JLabel("How many players ?");


    comboBoxPlayers = new JComboBox(playersChoises);

    if (comboBoxPlayers.getSelectedItem().equals("3")) {

        is3players = true;
    }

    if (comboBoxPlayers.getSelectedItem().equals("4")) {

        is3players = true;
        is4players = true;
    }

    JLabel writeNamesText = new JLabel("Set names of playes");

    writeNames = new JButton("set names");

    JLabel sizeOfBoredText = new JLabel("What the size of the bored ?");


    comboBoxSizes = new JComboBox(sizeChoises);

    startGame = new JButton("Click to start the game!");

    howManyPlayersText.setBounds(177, 200, 270, 100);
    comboBoxPlayers.setBounds(230, 270, 100, 30);
    writeNamesText.setBounds(230, 210, 380, 250);
    writeNames.setBounds(240, 350, 100, 36);
    sizeOfBoredText.setBounds(177, 376, 300, 100);
    comboBoxSizes.setBounds(230, 450, 100, 30);
    startGame.setBounds(200, 500, 200, 44);

    add(howManyPlayersText);
    add(comboBoxPlayers);
    add(writeNamesText);
    add(writeNames);
    add(sizeOfBoredText);
    add(comboBoxSizes);
    add(startGame);

    setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // open this class
    new SettingMenu();

    // when i click on startgame bottun open the class of the game

    startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new LeadersAndSnake_Project201();
        }
    });
```

// when i click on writeNames bottun open the class of dialog

```
    writeNames.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new SetNames();
        }
    });

}
```

}

and this is Set Names class which open the set names window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfFQO.png)

```
class SetNames extends JDialog {

public JTextField setNamePlayer1, setNamePlayer2, setNamePlayer3, setNamePlayer4;

public SetNames() {
    this.setSize(280, 151);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JLabel name1 = new JLabel("Set Player's 1 name : ");
    setNamePlayer1 = new JTextField(7);
    setNamePlayer1.setText("Player 1");

    JLabel name2 = new JLabel("Set Player's 2 name : ");
    setNamePlayer2 = new JTextField(7);
    setNamePlayer2.setText("Player 2");

    JPanel panelOfDialog_1 = new JPanel();

    panelOfDialog_1.add(name1);
    panelOfDialog_1.add(setNamePlayer1);

    JPanel panelOfDialog_2 = new JPanel();

    panelOfDialog_2.add(name2);
    panelOfDialog_2.add(setNamePlayer2);

    JPanel panelOfDialog_3 = new JPanel();

    JButton okBotton = new JButton("OK");

    add(okBotton);

    okBotton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            setNamePlayer1 = new JTextField(setNamePlayer1.getText());
            setNamePlayer2 = new JTextField(setNamePlayer2.getText());
            setVisible(false);

        }
    });

    panelOfDialog_3.add(okBotton);

    add(panelOfDialog_1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(panelOfDialog_2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(panelOfDialog_3, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

    this.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

and this is the large class for the game but I just put the imprtant thinga here :

```
class LeadersAndSnake_Project201 extends  JFrame implements ActionListener{

// Here I made an object of Setting Menu class for use the varible that it has
 SettingMenu obj1 = new SettingMenu();

// Here I made an object of Set Names  class to take the name inside the textfiled
 SetNames obj2 = new SetNames();


 public LeadersAndSnake_Project201() {

    // -----------------left panel------------------------------

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(leftPanel);
        leftPanel.setLayout(groupLayout);


        //---------------------------panel 1 for information player 1 -------------------------------------

        JPanel panel1  = new JPanel();


        ImageIcon imageMan1 = new ImageIcon("man1.png");
        JLabel imageMan11 = new JLabel("", imageMan1, JLabel.CENTER);


        JLabel player1text = new JLabel(obj2.setNamePlayer1.getText());



        panel1.add(imageMan11);
        panel1.add(player1text);

        //---------------------------panel 2 for information player 2------------------------------------

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();


        ImageIcon imageMan2 = new ImageIcon("man2.png");
        JLabel imageMan22 = new JLabel("", imageMan2, JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel player2text = new JLabel(obj2.setNamePlayer2.getText());

        panel2.add(imageMan22);
        panel2.add(player2text);

        //---------------------------panel 3 for information player 3-------------------------------------

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

         if(obj.is3 == true){


             ImageIcon imageMan3 = new ImageIcon("man3.png");
        JLabel imageMan33 = new JLabel("", imageMan3, JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel player3text = new JLabel("Player 3");
        player2text.setFont(fontText);
        panel3.add(imageMan33);
        panel3.add(player3text);


         }

 }
```

}

Here on left panel are my problems 
the jlable of player 1 and player 2 didn't chang even if I try to change them in the textfiled and the second problem is that the panel of player 3 didn't apper even if I select the chois "3" from the combox .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RRDU.jpg)

Comment: Something important seems to be missing from the code. Where are you adding the panels to leftPanel, and where are you adding leftPanel to the frame? Also careful, you are not setting player3text font, you have a copy/paste error there, player2text font is getting set again.

Comment: yeah I didn't paste the whole code here because it is too large I just paste the things that contain the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call .pack() on the Frame after altering the elements.

EDIT

You have no code changing the labels. What you need is store the labels in a variable, like you did with other components, and in the ActionListener on on the okButton in SetNames(), instead of doing whatever you do to the TextFields there (which looks wrong), update the Label text.

So, for example

```
class SetNames extends JDialog {

[...]
public JButton okButton; // save okButton so others can add listeners

}


class LeadersAndSnake_Project201 extends  JFrame implements ActionListener{


// Here I made an object of Set Names  class to take the name inside the textfiled
 SetNames obj2 = new SetNames();


 public LeadersAndSnake_Project201() {
[...]
 obj2.okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){/*update labels*/});

 }}
```

Comment: my problem is not about to arrange them or that they didn't show but it is that they don't change , maybe because the objects of the classes

Comment: Ah ok, updating my answer.